# Better OLED resolution and configuration with XPS 15

Tags: display-resolution, xps

The native OLED resolution 3456 x 2160 even with 200% scale is too small for me, I have the XPS 9510 with Ubuntu 21.04, Wayland and Kernel 5.13, the ideal resolution for my eyes is 1280 x 800, I have to options:

1. 2560 x 1600 with 200% scale: It looks sharper to me
2. 1280 x 800: A little bit blurry, but not much (maybe I am too tired already)

Which option would be better for: low CPU usage, better battery life, less wear to the OLED screen, and sharper/crisper image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always set a LCD/LED screen to its native resolution.  Anything else is going to look bad.

As you have already realized, you can scale the elements of the display to make them bigger without having to change the resolution.

As far as your concerns about wear to the panel, the screen resolution is irrelevant.

Presumably you might get slightly better battery life and/or CPU usage by having a smaller screen resolution, since your graphics adapter does not have to work as hard when rendering fewer overall pixels, but this is probably insignificant if you are just using a desktop environment and typical GUI applications.  It does make a difference in 3D rendering and gaming, but you can usually make these kinds of adjustments in the software settings without having to change away from your native resolution.

tl;dr: Always set your display to the native resolution.